# Lock, execute other code, set last write time, and unlock file

Tags: c#, .net, io, locking, filestream

An application I am working on uses `FileSystemWatcher` to execute code when last write time of a file is updated.

I want to lock an NTFS file (so other processes cannot access it), then execute some other code as an `Action`, then update the last write time

Something like,

```
// Lock the file to avoid concurrency issues due to multiple clients
using(var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)) {

    // Execute other code (MySQL, etc..)
    action();

    // TODO Update Last Write Time for file (To notify other listeners)

} // unlock
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: Now .NET framework source has an example of this - but it calls some system DLL files and I am not sure if I can implement a light version of that.

Comment: What example did you look at? What is your definition of "a light version"? Why is that a requirement? What have you tried so far? What happened? How was that different from what you wanted to happen? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. And maybe [`File.SetLastWriteTime()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setlastwritetime(v=vs.110).aspx) (but it's hard to tell from your question what you really need help with).

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,69cc34a7bce76481

Comment: ^ Implementing this would require implementing `Win32Native` and `__Error` - so that may not be the correct .NET way to (1) lock (2) execute action (3) update last write and (4) unlock file. I haven't tried this because it goes against platform agnosticism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into how SetLastWriteTime works,
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs
and
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/microsoft/win32/win32native.cs

Here is the implementation that fits my needs,

```
public struct FILE_TIME
{
    public FILE_TIME(long fileTime)
    {
        ftTimeLow = (uint)fileTime;
        ftTimeHigh = (uint)(fileTime >> 32);
    }

    public long ToTicks()
    {
        return ((long)ftTimeHigh << 32) + ftTimeLow;
    }

    public uint ftTimeLow;
    public uint ftTimeHigh;
}

internal const String KERNEL32 = "kernel32.dll";

[DllImport(KERNEL32, SetLastError = true)]
public unsafe static extern bool SetFileTime(SafeFileHandle hFile, FILE_TIME* creationTime,
            FILE_TIME* lastAccessTime, FILE_TIME* lastWriteTime);

public static void SetLastAccessTime(string fullPath, DateTime lastAccess, Action afterLock)
{
    long lastAccessTimeUtc = lastAccess.ToUniversalTime().ToFileTimeUtc();

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite, 1))
    {
        SafeFileHandle handle = fs.SafeFileHandle;

        if (!handle.IsInvalid)
        {
            afterLock();

            FILE_TIME fileTime = new FILE_TIME(lastAccessTimeUtc);

            bool r = SetFileTime(handle, null, &fileTime, null);

            if (!r)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note,
`SafeFileHandle` can be invalid and `SetFileTime` can return false under certain conditions.

Comment: In my application, which might have some subtle difference from yours, I was able to use File.SetLastWriteTime while I had the file open.